# Amazon SES - Connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-ses

I'm trying to create a template on `SES` sandbox version. I use the following code but I'm getting the following error. Please help me fix this.

```
        BasicAWSCredentials basicCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials("AXXXXXXXXXXXXX", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXi");
        AmazonSimpleEmailService client = null;
        try{
            client = AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2).withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(basicCreds)).build();
        } catch (Exception ex){
            logger.info(ex);
        }
        CreateTemplateRequest ctr = new CreateTemplateRequest();
        Template template = new Template();
        template.setTemplateName("Sample");
        template.setSubjectPart("Sample Mail");
        template.setTextPart("Test Mail from Template");
        ctr.setTemplate(template);
        client.createTemplate(ctr);
```

and the exception that I get is,

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: SIGNING_REGION
>       at com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient.executeCreateTemplate(AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient.java:950)
>       at com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient.createTemplate(AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient.java:932)

We are using ant build. If there is a jar problem please let me know which version of the jar I should be using.

Thanks in advance.